# Как сделать динамическую ссылку в angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Как сделать динамическую ссылку в angular?
Чтобы при нажатии первой кнопки - ссылка вела на гугл с запросом - "/search?q=angular", а вторая ссылка с запросом - "/search?q=javascript".
Нашел примерное решение на Stackblitz.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-router-link-jj6igy?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp%2Froot-page%2Froot-page.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Froot-page%2Froot-page.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html компонента, задаем в цикле ссылки, подменяя вторую часть, а host остается всегда одинаковым.

```
   <div *ngFor="let link of links">
      <a href="{{ host }}{{ link }}" target="_blank">{{ link }}</a>
    </div>
```

ts компонента, создаем поле host, который ведет на поиск гугла. А в массиве links описываем значение для поиска, который добавится во второй части ссылки

```
    host = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=';
    links = ['angular', 'javascript'];
```

Пример на [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lxnqed)

UPD. Для варианта, когда одна ссылка, а выбор идет через кнопки.

```
<div *ngFor="let link of links">
  <button (click)="activeLink = link">{{ link }}</button>
</div>
<a href="{{ host }}{{ activeLink }}" target="_blank">{{ activeLink }}</a>
```

ts

```
  host = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=';

  links = ['angular', 'javascript'];

  activeLink = this.links[0];
```

Меняем ссылки на кнопки, а при клике в поле `activeLink` записываем активную кнопку, по умлочанию она равна первому элементу.

Пример на [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mm6bap)

Comment: Спасибо, но мне требуется чтобы гиперрсылка была 1. И 2 кнопки, в зависимости от нажатия, гиперссылка вела бы на выбранный сайт.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-evclee?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html Так даже лучше будет для моего проекта. Т.е. у меня есть 1 слово, которое должно искаться на 2-х сайтах.

Comment: Добавил вариант, где выбор слова для поиска сделан через кнопки и одна ссылка.